# Is there a Mustache equivalent to Thymeleafs sec:authorize tag?

Tags: java, spring-security, thymeleaf, mustache

I'm working on porting an application with ThymeLeaf templates to use Mustache templates but I'm not finding a way good way to port the `sec:authorize` tags of ThymeLeaf. Is there a way to get at the `SecurityContext` information in Mustache like what is provided by the Thymeleaf Spring Security extras?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I thought I could use `@ControllerAdvice` to inject model attributes like this, but `SecurityContextHolder.getContents().getAuthentication()` is null. However I'm able to check roles on the `HttpServletRequest` object just fine. It seems like a timing issue because in my main `@Controller` I'm able to access the `Authentication` object. I can pull out the principal name, and `isAuthenticated()` returns the correct value. Here's what I tried with `@ControllerAdvice`:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.example.security.entity.UserRole;
import org.example.security.entity.UserRole.Role;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;

@ControllerAdvice
public class TemplateAdvice {

    private static String ANONYMOUS_USER = "anonymousUser";

    private Authentication authentication;

    private Object principal;

    private String username;

    private boolean isAuthenticated;

    private boolean isAnonymous;

    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public TemplateAdvice() {
        this.authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication();
        if (this.authentication != null) {
            this.principal = this.authentication.getPrincipal();
            this.username = this.authentication.getName();
        }
        this.isAnonymous = this.principal == null 
            || this.username.equals(ANONYMOUS_USER);
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addDefaultAttributes(HttpServletRequest request, 
            Model model) {
        this.request = request;

        model.addAttribute("isAuthenticated", this.authentication.isAuthenticated());
        model.addAttribute("isAnonymous", this.isAnonymous);
        model.addAttribute("username", this.username);
        model.addAttribute("isAuthenticated", hasAnyRole()); // hack
        model.addAttribute("isAdminOrSuper", 
            hasRole(UserRole.Role.ADMIN) 
                || hasRole(UserRole.Role.SUPER)); // this works
    }

    private boolean hasRole(Role role) {
        return this.request.isUserInRole(role.name());
    }

    private boolean hasAnyRole() {
        return Stream.of(UserRole.Role.values())
            .anyMatch(role -> hasRole(role));
    }
}
```

I'm pulling out the `contextPath` and `_csrf.token` by using,

```
spring.mustache.expose-request-attributes=true
spring.mustache.request-context-attribute=req
```

and was hoping some of the security context could be exposed similarly.

I'm not finding many examples on Google. Is there a good way to check if a user is authenticated and what roles they have in Mustache templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined one of the issues was that the security context was not resolving in the `TemplateAdvice` constructor. After moving it to `addDefaultAttributes` everything functioned as expected. Here's what I came up with for now:

```
package com.example.authentication.server.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import com.example.authentication.server.security.SecurityHelper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;

@ControllerAdvice
public class TemplateAdvice {

    private SecurityHelper securityHelper;

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addDefaultAttributes(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        securityHelper = new SecurityHelper(SecurityContextHolder.getContext());

        model.addAttribute("isLoggedIn", securityHelper.isAuthenticated() 
            && !securityHelper.isAnonymous());
        model.addAttribute("username", securityHelper.username());
        model.addAttribute("isAdminOrSuper", securityHelper.isAdminOrSuper());
    }
}
```

And the corresponding `SecurityHelper` class:

```
package com.example.authentication.server.security;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;

public class SecurityHelper {

    public static enum Role {
        ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN;
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = 
        Collections.emptyList();

    private Authentication authentication;

    public SecurityHelper(SecurityContext context) {
        authentication = context.getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null) {
            authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
        }
    }

    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return authentication == null ? false : authentication.isAuthenticated();
    }

    public boolean isAnonymous() {
        return authentication == null ? true : 
            authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken;
    }

    public String username() {
        return authentication == null ? "" : authentication.getName();
    }

    public boolean isAdminOrSuper() {
        return hasAnyRole(Arrays.asList(Role.ROLE_ADMIN, Role.ROLE_SUPER));
    }

    /**
    * Checks if user contains the given role.
    * 
    * @param role
    *            A user role.
    * @return True if the user contains the role.
    */
    public boolean hasRole(Role role) {
        return authorities == null ? false
                : authorities.stream().anyMatch(authority -> 
                    authority.getAuthority().equals(role.name()));
    }

    /**
    * Checks if a user contains at least one of the roles.
    * 
    * @param roles
    *            A list of user roles.
    * @return True if the user contains one of the roles.
    */
    public boolean hasAnyRole(List<Role> roles) {
        return roles.stream().anyMatch(role -> hasRole(role));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made a starter for mustache to use spring security's 'Expression-Based Access Control' feature, please check the codes here:
https://github.com/iceant/mustache-security-spring-boot-starter

Here is the examples:

```
{{#sec:hasRole('ADMIN')}}<li>ADMIN CONTENT</li>{{/sec:hasRole('ADMIN')}}
{{#sec:hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('USER')}}<li>ADMIN & USER CONTENT</li>{{/sec:hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('USER')}}
{{#sec:hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'USER')}}<li>ADMIN OR USER CONTENT</li>{{/sec:hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'USER')}}
{{#sec:hasRole('USER')}}<li>USER CONTENT</li>{{/sec:hasRole('USER')}}
{{#sec:isAnonymous()}}<li>isAnonymous</li>{{/sec:isAnonymous()}}{{^sec:isAnonymous()}}<li>isAnonymous=false</li>{{/sec:isAnonymous()}}
{{#sec:isRememberMe()}}<li>isRememberMe</li>{{/sec:isRememberMe()}}{{^sec:isRememberMe()}}<li>isRememberMe=false</li>{{/sec:isRememberMe()}}
{{#sec:isAuthenticated()}}<li>isAuthenticated</li>{{/sec:isAuthenticated()}}
{{^sec:isAuthenticated()}}<li>isAuthenticated=false</li>{{/sec:isAuthenticated()}}
{{#sec:isFullyAuthenticated()}}<li>isFullyAuthenticated</li>{{/sec:isFullyAuthenticated()}}
{{^sec:isFullyAuthenticated()}}<li>isFullyAuthenticated=false</li>{{/sec:isFullyAuthenticated()}}
{{#sec:principal}}<li>principal={{username}}{{/sec:principal}}
{{#sec:authentication}}<li>authentication={{.}}{{/sec:authentication}}
{{#sec:permitAll}}<li>permitAll</li>{{/sec:permitAll}}
{{#sec:denyAll}}<li>denyAll</li>{{/sec:denyAll}}
{{^sec:denyAll}}<li>denyAll=false</li>{{/sec:denyAll}}
{{^sec:hasIpAddress('192.168.2.1')}}<li>hasIpAddress('192.168.2.1')=false</li>{{/sec:hasIpAddress('192.168.2.1')}}
{{#sec:isMember(3)}}<li>isMember(3){{/sec:isMember(3)}}

{{#sec:@webSecurity.check(authentication,request)}}<li>@webSecurity.check(authentication,request){{/sec:@webSecurity.check(authentication,request)}}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)